# Checking for Int in Array . Swift 3, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, int, sender

I have the following code:

```
print (sender.tag) // prints 21  (example)
print(DictPl2) // prints [0, 1, 20, 21, 84, 94, 26, 27, 37, 55, 56, 66, 52, 53, 54, 55, 72, 73, 74, 75]
var DictPl2 = [Int]()
if playeractive == 1 {
 for i in DictPl2 {
                if i == sender.tag {
                    print("Well done")
                    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                }

                else {    //always goes this
                    print("Bad")
                    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
                }
            }
```

I am checking if sender.tag does equal to any of elements in array DictPl2. But if it does or doesn't equal, the code always goes the marked way. Anyone knows, what might be the mistake?
Thank you

Comment: Con you also log i and log sender.tag? May be you are not setting sender's tag correctly?

Comment: Note that you execute the comparison for *all* array elements – the last element wins!

Comment: I see, also thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `DictPl2.contains(sender.tag)` instead of your `for loop`. Then your code would look like:

```
if DictPL2.contains(sender.tag) {
    print("Well done")
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
} else {
    print("Bad")
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
}
```

Comment: Great, works, Thanks! But no idea why the code did not work then.

Comment: @TobyV. Can you accept it as an answer since it works? :)

Comment: @StefanStefanov you can simplify your code using the ternary operator `sender.backgroundColor = DictPL2.contains(sender.tag) ? .red :  .brown`

Comment: I was thinking about it but maybe he wants to keep his print() statements for debugging. But great suggestion @LeoDabus!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.2

```
if DictPL2.contains(where: {$0 == sender.tag) {
    print("Well done")
} else {
    print("Bad")
}
```

Please check [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains).